# Share file .txt Android

Tags: java, android, file, share, sharing

I'm trying to share a .txt file to another app (gmail for example) but I have some problems. I decided to use the file provider. When I select gmail among the apps to share the file with, the app returns me the "Couldn't attach file" toast.

I write the file txt in internal memory with this method:

```
public void esportaTxt(Graph graph, int id){
        final String FILE_NAME = id + "_TXT" + ".txt";
        List<Zona> zone = new ArrayList<>();
        Iterator<Zona> iterator = graph.vertexSet().iterator();

        zone = fromIteratorToArrayZone(iterator);

        File fileOutputFolder = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "fileOutput"); //cartella in cui salvare i file da condividere

        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
        try {
            fileOutputFolder.mkdirs(); //crea la cartella se non esiste
            File file = new File(fileOutputFolder, FILE_NAME); //il file da salvare

            fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

            for(int i = 0; i < zone.size(); i++){
                fileOutputStream.write((i + 1 + ") " + zone.get(i).getNome() + "\n").getBytes());

                Iterator<Oggetto> iteratoreOggetti = zone.get(i).getListaOggetti().iterator();
                while (iteratoreOggetti.hasNext()){
                    fileOutputStream.write(("   - " + iteratoreOggetti.next().getNome() + "\n").getBytes());
                }
            }

            contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "com.example.eculturetool.fileprovider", file);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(fileOutputStream != null){
                try {
                    fileOutputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I share the file txt with the following method:

```
public void shareFileTxt(int id){
        String fileName = id + "_TXT.txt";
        String stringFile = context.getFilesDir() +  "/fileOutput" +  File.separator + fileName;

        File file = new File(stringFile);
        contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "com.example.eculturetool.fileprovider", file);

        if(!file.exists()){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Il file non esiste!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }


        Intent intentShare = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intentShare.setType("text/*");
        intentShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject Here"); //per condividere con email app
        intentShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, contentUri);
        intentShare.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intentShare, "Condividi file"));
    }
```

The permissions that I require in the Activity:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
        StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());
```

Provider in android manifest:

```
<provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.eculturetool.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
```

The screen of Gmail
[image]

Comment: Why is the exported tag false?

Comment: From documentation: Set the android:exported attribute to false; the FileProvider does not need to be public.

Comment: ok. But, I doubt a bit on `intentShare.setType("text/*");`. Might be I am wrong

Comment: `The permissions that I require in the Activity:` You do not need that permission for getFilesDir().

Comment: Try without the chooser.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and spent a lot of time on it. But the solution was not in the code.
On my Xiaomi device, the "MIUI optimisation" setting was disabled. It is located at the bottom of the developer's options. After I enabled it, file sharing started to work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

you must grant uri permission before starting intentShare ,
like this code:

```
context.grantUriPermission(
                "your.package.name",
                contentUri,
                Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
            )
```